# wet cat food dispenser - Pet Feeding Robot - is this https://pawbot.com/?

Tags: us20130247829

In reference to the patent: [US20130247829](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130247829) *Pet Feeding Robot . Automatic Pet Wet Food Dispenser Robot*

Is this patent the same as https://pawbot.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your question. Notice that pawbot is a robot, not a patent.

After a quick reading it seems that pawbot reproduce all the characteristics of the object of the claim 1 of the patent but without more information there isn't much conclusion that can be drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct - https://pawbot.com/ is our website and PawBot the robot utilizes the claims of this patent. Feel free to directly contact us using the contact-us form on our website.

Thanks!
Kevin Tye

Comment: I wasn't sure if this deserved a flag or an upvote, but decided for the upvote in the end as it *does* answer the question, although the question should probably be closed.